# Module files needed to run an application in gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I have an application in gradle divided into several modules https://zapodaj.net/745369ca57478.png.html. I want to throw him onto GitHub now. I'm not sure which files are needed. I currently have added in the gitignore file

```
# gradle config
.gradle/

# Intellij Idea project files
.idea/
out/
*.iml

# project binaries
build/`
```

In each .gitigore file I have typed the same thing. But in modules, I do not need files, perhaps

```
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

Can I remove these two files from the modules and only stay out of the modules only? It seems to me that these two files are only needed outside the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you already include all the module in setting.gradle, then you don't need those 2 file and the gradle folder in each module

```
include ":core", ":common", ":web"
```